# Calling @odata.nextlink from powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to call the *odata.nextlink* from a powershell script im writing to get Azure AD signin information for users.

```
$LastLogin = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $AuthHeader1 -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity" -Verbose
$result = ($LastLogin.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).Value
$result  | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{n="LastLoginDate";e={$_.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime}}
```

and it results in the first 100 results being disaplayed

if I view the $lastLogin output I can see the content includes the odata.nextlink option but I can't seem to get the uri to pass into a while loop to get all the results

[$lastLogin output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7xcz.png)

if I do $lastLogin."@odata.nextLink' it just returns a null value.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

In the second step rather using the

```
$result = ($LastLogin.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).Value
```

Use `$result = ($LastLogin.Content | ConvertFrom-Json)` and then pull the nextLink using the `$result.'@odata.nextLink'`

It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: so i think this is where i was going wrong...but i still couldn't get it to work when using invoke-webrequest, i had to change it to invoke-restmethod and then i was able to call the nextLink as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this is how I use @odata.nextLink :

```
    # get a list of deleted users to check against
    $graphPages = @()
    $delUsersUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user"
    $delUsers = ( Invoke-GraphRequest -Uri $delUsersUri -Method Get -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop ) 
    $graphPages += $delUsers.Value 

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan ( Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy-hhmmss" ) "Connecting to Graph and fetching results for deleted users"

    if ( $delUsers.'@odata.nextLink' )
    {
        do 
        {
            # Graph API is limited to 100 per page, loop through '@odata.nextLink' until it's not a valid property
            $delUsers = ( Invoke-GraphRequest -Uri $delUsers.'@odata.nextLink' -Method Get -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop )
            $graphPages += $delUsers.value

        } until ( ! ( $delUsers.'@odata.nextLink')  )
    }
    # set Variable for total count of deleted users entries
    $delUsersList = $graphPages
```